# You can not complete this action for this component because of the configuration of its managed properties

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

I am trying to make a field optional in the Dynamics CRM

The name of the entity is Case and the internal name of the field is customerid

When I try to change it from mandatory to optional, I get the below error message

> You can not complete this action for this component because of the
>   configuration of its managed properties.

this is happening in Dynamics CRM online

Comment: You may need to create solution and include the entity with the field. And then try to make the necessary changes.

Comment: Thank you. I just tried it, but it doesn't seem to work. Got the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you won't be able to.

It's one of the few fields where mandatory behaviour is enforced at the platform level, whilst most mandatory fields are enforced only on the user interface.

If I remember correctly, tring to create a case without a customer via the API will result in an exception.

Looking at the managed properties for the customerid field on my recently provisioned CRM Online, shows that I'm unable to change the requirement level - I don't even get the option for setting it as optional.

Comment: I added it to the form and now I am not able to remove it now. Hiding it doesn't help either.
 Any workarounds?

Comment: @vignesh Subramanian I think you could hand edit the form xml and then reimport it.  I believe the check for having it on the form is only enforced via the UI

Comment: I don't see any option to import/export XML in the form design page. Can you please provide some links

Comment: I used XRMToolkit and edited the xml and removed the field :)

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to remove the field from the form, but I was not able to do it from the UI

So I used [XRMToolBox](https://www.xrmtoolbox.com/).

There is a plugin called as FormXML Manager, enable it in the XRMToolBox and load the entities. Once this is done you can remove the required field and publish the form

[image]